# Creating SYMLINK with PHP on Hostgator jailed shell - Get Perm Denied error

Tags: php, linux, shell

so I come to you with this problem:

GIVENS:

1. I have Hostgator as the ISP.
2. I'm using PHP 5.5
3. The LINUX box is CENTOS
4. Shared Hosting Environment
5. I am a professional coder and experienced with LAMP for many years

PROBLEMS:

1. I'm NOT familiar with Jailed Shell but have an idea
2. I've tried the script and have been searching for an answer
3. Still Stuck...

Here's my current code:

```
function getMyFakeDir($myfile) {

    $target = "";
    $link = 'content/purchased-items/link';
    symlink($target, $link);

    echo "READ LINK: ". readlink($link);

    return readlink($link);

}
```

Here's the called to the function:

```
$linkText = getMyFakeDir('SomePDFThatTheUserCanDownload.pdf');
```

Then I pass that "$linkText" var to PHPMailer and wala!!! The user clicks to download through the Symlink and I've written a code to make it expire after 24 hours. Yeah, I got that from PHP.net.

So, basically that's my problem....

Here's the error:

```
Warning: symlink(): Permission denied in /homeSomewhere/someMasterDir/public_html/webServices/somePHPFile.php on line 654
```

This is link 654 from above:
    symlink($target, $link);

Thanks...

Comment: BTW the directory where the documents that are paid for through PAYPAL, are located are here:  public_html/content/purchased-items/ and the directory where this PHP file is located is here:  public_html/webServices/myPHPfile.php

Comment: Your target is empty... ?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that here! http://forums.hostgator.com/create-symbolic-link-t237741.html and was basing my knowledge from that article.  My $target should be the document the "current REAL" path PLUS the document, correct?

Comment: The target should be the absolute or relative path to the actual file you are trying to link to.

Comment: So therefore like this:  "/homeSomewhere/someMasterDir/public_html/content/" <-- THIS is the MAIN directory for all content then in there are these two directories:  /free-gifts and /purchased-items

Comment: Did you show us the relevant code? The effective call to symlink() reads as `symlink("",'content/purchased-items/link')`, doesn't it? I'm not surprised that it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.... Simple LOGIC!

First I had the PATHS all wrong. Here's the CORRECTED CODE:

```
//Generate Symbolic Link that blows away a fake directory each time
//A symbolic Link is created to "THIS" file below
$filename = $myfile;
//This is ANY directory on the server...
//A randomly named directory is created here...STEP 1
$downloaddir = "/home/someHostDir/public_html/sldktrulwiu2555ivd0fjvdfgdfgdfgdf/";
//Any directory NOT accessible by a browser - This is one level up
$safedir = "/home/someHostDir/content/purchased-items/";
//This is the equivalent of the $downloaddir and the browser is REDIRECTED here and the download begins
$downloadURL = "http://www.theSomeDomain.com/sldktrulwiu2555ivd0fjvdfgdfgdfgdf/"; //THIS IS THE FAKE DIRECTORY (Which I simply type gobbligook and created that mess above)
$letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
$string = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= rand(4, 12); $i++) {
    $q = rand(1, 24);
    $string = $string . $letters[$q];
}

$handle = opendir($downloaddir);
while ($dir = readdir($handle)) {
    if (is_dir($downloaddir . $dir)) {
        if ($dir != "." && $dir != "..") {
            @unlink($downloaddir . $dir . "/" . $filename);
            @rmdir($downloaddir . $dir);
        }
    }
}
closedir($handle);
mkdir($downloaddir . $string, 0777);
symlink($safedir . $filename, $downloaddir . $string . "/" . $filename);
//Header("Location: " . $downloadURL . $string . "/" . $filename);
```

That just about does it.

The result is a Dynamic directory inside the "/sldktrulwiu2555ivd0fjvdfgdfgdfgdf/" directory like this: "dfsgss/" and a "shortcut" to the REAL LOCATION where the files are. THEN when the file is downloaded, and the page returns to the INDEX.HTML, the code BLOWS OUT the FAKE directory Never more to be seen again. Thus, if the user wants to go back, they get the horrible 404 PAGE error that the file / has been moved or deleted.  BUMMER.

That's it folks. Thanks for your assistance, it was you all the helped me release my error. TEAM WORK!